# Why AlarmManager cancel does not work?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

Hi I'm trying to cancel AlarmManager. I wrote some test code but It,s not working, my code:

Alarm creation:

```
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,NotificationService.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntentFriday = PendingIntent.getService(this,123098,myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);         
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,nextFriday.getTimeInMillis() , pendingIntentFriday);
```

Alarm cancel:

```
            Intent stopIntent = new Intent(this,NotificationService.class);
            PendingIntent stopFriday = PendingIntent.getService(this,123098,stopIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager stopManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            stopManager.cancel(stopFriday);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12119147/726863

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your flag to "FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT"

Answer (score -3):

```
 AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReceiverForCancelling.class);
  PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
  PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
   service.cancel(pending)
```